# How to Remove "Insert Paragraph Here" Pointer? in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

When I Move My Cursor to the end of the text in CKEditor a Pointer with a Red Line Appear Saying "Inser Paragraph Here". For More Clarification, Here is its Snapshot.

[image]

Please Tell me How Can I Stop It from Appearing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a magicline plugin. Add:

```
removePlugins: 'magicline'
```

to your config file/startup configuration and it's gone for good.